# IP Address Blocking

Tags: iptables

My server was hit by a flood from a single IP targeting a specific port (7777), which was captured using tcpdump, like so:

16:38:35.079994 IP 20.195.191.67.58074 > 12.34.56.78.7777: UDP, length 4

I attempted to block the source IP using two methods:

```
ip route add blackhole 20.195.191.67/32
iptables -A INPUT -s 20.195.191.67 -j DROP
```

However, tcpdump reported no change - the traffic from the IP kept coming. And my server was still feeling the effect of it (services barely responsive).

Am I missing something here? Why did my attempt to block the IP have no impact at all?

Comment: In order to process a packet, it must first arrive at the NIC. `tcpdump` reports what arrives at the NIC, so you will see traffic even if the kernel then DROPs it.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something here? Why did my attempt to block the IP have no impact at all?

Unless you have something running on port 7777 ([Unreal tournament server?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)) then those packets were going to be dropped anyway.  Telling iptables to specifically drop them only prevents Linux from looking for a program listening on that port.  The packets still reach the server and are processed.

This is one big reason for having a dedicated firewall and then only opening up the ports on your server that you really need.  Most come with some sort of flood detection / prevention for this type of scenario.

Unfortunately, if someone is able to flood your server by sending packets to a single port (which isn't used) then there's not much you can do to prevent this on the server itself.

Comment: So, having UFW installed and Enabled should do the work, right?

Comment: No dedicated firewall here means a separate physical device.  That can be firewall configurations built into your internet router, an off-the-shelf firewall (hardware device) or a separate computer who's only job is to be a firewall.  If this is a virtual machines in the cloud, cloud providers offer their own solutions to this such as AWS "Security Groups"

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, your server still needs to deal with the packets, iptables / firewalls or not. What you could try to do is block the IP on your router, or by funneling all your traffic through a "Cloudflare"-like service, which would handle the IP-blocking for you (and not make your hardware have to deal with the packet flood)

Comment: He literally tried to block it and is wondering why it did not work...

Comment: @number9 The thing is, it worked. Packets will always arrive on the network interface, regardles of whether you bother to block them or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe think about installing fail2ban it does automatically block attacks from specific ips. I guess it would work out if your doing it now.

Regarding iptables did you: `service iptables save`